# Modifying mini-toc content

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir, titletoc

I have adapted the [pretty table of contents solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents) written by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) with the modification to the "blue box style" that [Stephan Lehmke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12850/stephan-lehmke) helped me with to design a somewhat consistent look-and-feel for chapter heads and table of contents, as illustrated below.  However, I am facing one last problem that has me stomped.

For the MWE example below, the table of contents looks like the following, where I have changed some of the colors for the chapter names.

[image: Table of contents]

A "typical" chapter head, that includes a mini table of contents looks as follows:

[image: Correct chapter head]

However, a "typical" Appendix head has the Appendix title repeated in the mini table of contents:

[image: Incorrect Appendix head]

Note that I can achieve (!) the same look for a chapter if I include the package `titletoc` at the beginning of the preamble rather than at the end, as illustrated below.
[image: Incorrect chapter head]

In other words, in order to include the proper amount of material in the mini table of contents at the beginning of a chapter, I need to include `titletoc` after I include the code to create the "pretty table of contents"; somehow, `titletoc` must redefine some macros which, perhaps (?) are rewritten when `\appendix` is interpreted - or perhaps are not defined in `titletoc` in the first place.

So, how do I get rid of the extra "Appendix title" in the mini table of contents?

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}   % for testing purpose only
\usepackage{mdframed}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyphenat}       % I use it to prevent hyphenation of table of contents items
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%% Do not include titletoc here - do it at the end
 %\usepackage{titletoc}             

%%% colors definitions
\definecolor{MainRed}{rgb}{.6, .1, .1}
\definecolor{GoldDecoration}{RGB}{170, 120, 70}

% Colored section, subsections, as well as
% chapter and section name in the head - included for completeness
\setsecheadstyle{\color{MainRed}\large\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\color{MainRed}\bfseries}
\copypagestyle{myheadings}{headings}
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\thepage}{}{\color{MainRed}\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{\color{MainRed}\rightmark}{}{\thepage}

%% RedBox style -- adapted from BlueBox style, pp:43-44
% http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf
% with modifications from 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49864/automatically-adjusting-size-of-a-box-based-on-other-content
% and others modifications of my own
\newcommand{\RedBarLength}{3em}

\newsavebox{\ChpNumBox}
\newsavebox{\ChpContBox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\thickhrulefill}{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 3\p@ \hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand*\BuildChpNum[3]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \makebox[0pt][c]{#1\strut} \\[.5ex]
    \colorbox{MainRed}{%
      \rule[-\RedBarLength-(#3)]{0pt}{0pt}%
      \rule{1ex}{0pt}\color{white}#2\strut
      \rule{1ex}{0pt}}%
  \end{tabular}}
\makechapterstyle{BoxedChapNum}{%
  \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\large\scshape}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-30pt}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{10pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{30pt}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \sbox{\ChpContBox}{%
      \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\color{blue}}%
      }}%
    \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
      \BuildChpNum{\color{GoldDecoration}\bfseries\chapnamefont\@chapapp}%
      {\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
      {\ht\ChpContBox+\dp\ChpContBox}%
    }}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{%
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \sbox{\ChpContBox}{%
      \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        %\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}%  Useless?
      }}%
    \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
      \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\vphantom{\@chapapp}}%
      {\chapnumfont\hphantom{\thechapter}}%
      {\ht\ChpContBox+\dp\ChpContBox}%
    }}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
    \parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
      \raggedright\vspace{\midchapskip}%
        {\color{GoldDecoration}\thickhrulefill}\\[10pt]
      {\chaptitlefont\LARGE\textcolor{MainRed}{\nohyphens{##1}}}\par\vspace*{10pt}
      \renewcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{black}}
      \renewcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{black}}
      \renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\sffamily\color{MainRed}}
      \renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\sffamily\color{MainRed}}
      \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}%
    }}%
} 
\makeatother 

%%%%%% use the newly defined style
\chapterstyle{BoxedChapNum}

%%% Pretty ToC
%%%%% adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents/35835
% a modification of the leftbar environment defined by the framed package
% will be used to place a vertical colored bar separating the page number and the
% title in chapter entries
\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\textcolor{GoldDecoration}{\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace*{15pt}}%
  \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\makeatletter

% redefinitions for chapter entries
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\mbox{\small\@chapapp~#1}\par\noindent\Large}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\sffamily}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0em}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{MainRed}}

\newcommand*{\l@mychap}[3]{%
  \def\@chapapp{\color{MainRed}#3}
  \vskip1ex%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill{\cftchapterpagefont#2}%
  }\hspace*{1.5em}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5em-15pt\relax}{%
    \leftbar\cftchapterfont{\color{MainRed}#1}\hspace{1sp}\endleftbar%
  }%
  \end{minipage}\par%
}
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}
\renewcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\appendixname}%
}

% redefinitions for section entries
\renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\sffamily\color{black}}
\renewcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{MainRed}}
\renewcommand\cftsectionleader{\nobreak}
\renewcommand\cftsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsectionafterpnum{\hspace*{\fill}}
\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{12em}
\cftsetindents{section}{6em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}

% redefinitions for subsection entries
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\sffamily\color{black}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\sffamily\itshape\color{MainRed}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionleader{\nobreak}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionafterpnum{\hspace*{\fill}}
\setlength\cftsubsectionnumwidth{12em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{9em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsubsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}
\makeatother

%%%% End of Pretty ToC

\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

% include after the change above
\usepackage{titletoc}   

\begin{document}
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\frontmatter
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter{Foreword}
    \lipsum[9]

\mainmatter
    \chapter{First Chapter}
        \lipsum[1]
        \section{First section}
        \lipsum[2]
        \subsection{First subsection}
        \lipsum[3]
        \section{Second section}
        \lipsum
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
        \section{First section}

    \appendix
    \chapter{First Appendix}
        \lipsum[7]
        \section{First section}
        \lipsum[8]
        \section{Second section}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have included a few extra lines (such as the color selection for section heads) as various attempts I have made have resulted in changing other elements; those included are the ones needed for the "complete look and feel".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `memoir` defines a "new" sectioning structure named `appendix` which gets its own `\l@appendix`. This doesn't exist in LaTeX standard classes. A chapter in the appendix is just a chapter.

`titletoc` now "hooks" into the commands `\l@`..., saving the old definitions at the time the package is loaded (this is the positional effect you have noticed; it would probably be better for `titletoc` to save the old definitions `\AtBeginDocument`, then it wouldn't make a difference when the package is loaded).

You are redefining the `\l@appendix`, but `titletoc` doesn't know about `\l@appendix` and thus doesn't hook into it.

I (naively!) mimicked `titletoc`s chapter hook for appendix like this:

```
\let\ttl@savel@appendix\l@appendix
\def\l@appendix{\let\ttl@savel@chapter\ttl@savel@appendix\ttl@lselect{chapter}}
```

(inserted immediately before `\makeatother` in your MWE)

This should make an appendix behave like a chapter as far as `titletoc` is concerned. You might make a less naive definition if you need chapters and appendices to behave differently. At least in my test, the redundant appendix heading disappeared.

Comment: This works very well, thank you. I really, really appreciate the explanation too.