# Format ToC in KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle

I want to make the page number *italic* in the ToC.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Similar to [Pretty Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35825/pretty-table-of-contents?lq=1)
and [Modifying mini-toc content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51351/modifying-mini-toc-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape}`. For the `nopagecolumn` style, make sure to use a font like Latin Modern that features the sans-serif/bold/italic combination.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]