# Modifying list of tables/images

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I'd like to customize the list of figures and tables with a similar design to this:

[Modifying mini-toc content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51351/modifying-mini-toc-content/261205#261205)

Does somebody know how to do a similar design for a list of tables/images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`titletoc` package can also be used to customize the list of figures and tables.  From the documentation of `\dottedcontents` and `\titlecontents` commands:

> "section" is the section name without backslash: part, chapter,
>   section, etc. figure and table are allowed, too. (The backlash is
>   omitted because we are dealing with the concept and not the `\part`,
>   `\section`, etc. macros themselves. Furthermore, figure and table are
>   environments.)

You can easily adapt the code in the mentioned answer to get the desired result:

```
\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar\textsc{\small Figure~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
  {}{\endleftbar}
```

> [image]

---

**EDIT 1:**

For further customization, you can extract the value of current chapter from the macro `\thecontentslabel`, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar 
   \textsc{\small \chaptername~\expandafter\@car\thecontentslabel\@nil\ // %
     Figure~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
  {}{\endleftbar}
\makeatother
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

You can insert any kind of material into a `lof` via `\addtocontents`.  E.g., you can define a command `\updatemylof` invoked after a `\chapter` to insert a title into your `lof` which is formatted like a section.  Maybe you can customize this approach to your needs.  Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,framed,titletoc,lmodern}

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{%
    \hspace{6em}%
    {\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}%
    \hspace{1em}%
  }%
  \MakeFramed{\parshape 1 0cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax\FrameRestore}\vskip2pt\relax
  }
 {\endMakeFramed}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar
   \textsc{\small\chaptername~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
  {}{\endleftbar}
\titlecontents{section}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [8.4em]
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{3em}}{}{}  
  {\hspace{0.5em}\nobreak\itshape\color{myred}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
  {\parbox{4.5em}{%
    \hfill\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{myred}\thecontentspage}%
   \vspace*{-2.3\baselineskip}\leftbar
   \textsc{\small Figure~\thecontentslabel}\\\sffamily}
  {}{\endleftbar}

\newcommand*\updatemylof{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\section*{Chapter~\thechapter}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with \LaTeX}
\section{This is a test section}
\subsection{Long subsection title and some other text to span more
  than one line}

\newpage\setcounter{page}{123}% just for the example

\chapter{Beginning to learn design with HTML and some other text to
  span more than one line in the ToC}
\updatemylof

\section{This is a test section}
\subsection{Long subsection title and some other text to span more
  than one line}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption of figure}\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption of figure}\end{figure}

\chapter{Further learning}
\updatemylof

\begin{figure}\caption{Caption of figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption of figure}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. Could be possible to include "the chapter+label" between the figures/tables? Chapter 1// figure 1.1//figure 1.2// Chapter 2//figure 2.1//figure 2.2

Comment: @lom - See Edit in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I want. I would like to include each group of figures/tables after their 'Chapter+label'. I did not explain it in a proper way on the last comment (I'm sorry): **Chapter 1** \\ figure 1.1\\ figure 1.2\\    **Chapter 2**  \\ figure 2.1\\ figure 2.2

Comment: @lom - And chances are good that I still don't understand what you are looking for.  Check edit 2 in my answer.